# type error of Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

Tags: swift

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            func CheckInput() { //<-- here the error
                if(name == "") {
                    self.showAlertC1 = true
                }
                else if(!checkInput(name)) {
                    self.showAlertC2 = true
                }
                else {
                       NavigationLink(destination: DisplayView(name: name)){
                                Text("Tap Me")
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
            Text("enter you name")
            TextField("Enter your name...", text: $name, onEditingChanged: { [weak self] (editing) in
                        if !editing {
                            self?.checkInput()
                        }
                    })
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlertC1) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Input is empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlertC2) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Input is not valid"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
```

so I got error (Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder')

basically if user after finish typing or click "enter keyboard" its should goes to the func and check the input and if there anything wrong should popup alert explaining the problem

`@State private var name: String = ""`
`@State private var showAlertC1 = false`
`@State private var showAlertC2 = false`

`func checkInput(_ input: String) -> Bool { let alphabet = CharacterSet.letters return input.rangeOfCharacter(from: alphabet) != nil }`

Comment: Why is `func CheckInput() { ... }` inside `VStack(...) { ... here ... }`? Should it be at the same "level" as `var body: some View { ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

You just can't put something like this is a view:

```
   func CheckInput() {
                if(name == "") {
                    self.showAlertC1 = true
                }
                else if(!checkInput(name)) {
                    self.showAlertC2 = true
                }
                else {
                       NavigationLink(destination: DisplayView(name: name)){
                                Text("Tap Me")
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
```

First of all, you can't put a func inside a var!

Second: All you put inside a View should return a View. NavigationLink is a View, but self.showAlertC1 and self.showAlertC2 are not Views.

Please follow some tutorials how to use SwiftUI.

Your code should be something like this:

```
@State private var nameIsValid = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            if nameIsValid {
                NavigationLink(destination: DisplayView(name: name)){
                    Text("Tap Me")
                })
            }
            Text("enter you name")
            TextField("Enter your name...", text: $name, onEditingChanged: { [weak self] (editing) in
                if !editing {
                    self?.checkInput()
                }
            })
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlertC1) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Input is empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlertC2) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Input is not valid"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
    
func checkInput(name: String) {
    if (name.isEmpty) {
        self.showAlertC1 = true
    } else if(!isValid(name)) {
        self.showAlertC2 = true
    } else {
        nameIsValid = true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! its working and I promise ill see swift course